# Understanding rotation matrix direction

Tags: matrices, rotations

In this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLX8T.png) I want to compute the distance of the red en blue line, which in this example is ~0.6 and ~3.1 respectively. I thought i might be able to use a rotation matrix for this problem.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y' \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(a) & -sin(a) \\
sin(a) & cos(a) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So i rotate the original x and y-axis by 30 degree counter clockwise so the x-axis aligns with the dotted black line.

Now my question is as follows: when i enter a positive angle (+30) i don't get the values i expect to get (-0.6 and 3.1). However, when i enter a negative angle (-30) i get the correct values. Could someone explain this to me, because i assumed counter clockwise rotation counts as positive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to the graph you should not turn neither 30 nor -30. Maybe you could comment on that so I know if your graph is wrong or maybe it's the angle.

Comment: @Zaragosa Tan-1 (4/7) = 29.74 degree

Comment: @DavidK I want to compute the lengths of the red and blue line with the help of a rotation matrix. But, i don't understand why i have to take a negative angle of -30 degree to get the lengths of these lines

Comment: Re-reading the question, I see the point of confusion now.

Comment: I think it is easier to think that the line is the product of a rotation of the X axis. In this way we have to "return" it to its place by rotating clockwise $\arctan(4/7)\approx 29.74$ degrees. And just what you did (I think so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of confusion seems to be between a matrix for a *rotation* versus a matrix for a *change of coordinates*.

The concept of a *rotation* matrix assumes that you want to leave the axes fixed in place.
Taking a matrix $A$ for a $30$ degree counterclockwise rotation,
for each pair of coordinates $[x\ y]^T$ you put the matrix on the left side of the coordinate vector, multiply, and obtain a new set of coordinates $[x'\ y']^T$.
When you take these new coordinates and plot them **relative to the original axes**,
you will plot an image of your original point which is $30$ degrees counterclockwise from the position of the original point.

In short: by putting the positive angle $30$ degrees (or $29.74$ degrees) into your rotation matrix and applying it to the coordinates $[3\ 1]^T,$ you obtain the coordinates of a point somewhere above and to the left of the point at $[3\ 1]^T,$
plotted according to the horizontal and vertical axes of your original coordinate system. The first coordinate will be less than $3$ (because it rotated to the left),
and the second coordinate will be greater than $1$ (because it rotated upward).

The matrix for a *change of coordinates* is the exact opposite of the matrix for a rotation. In a $30$ degree counterclockwise rotation, you want points on the $x$ axis to end up above the $x$ axis. But in a $30$ counterclockwise change of coordinates,
you want some of the points that started at locations above the $x$ axis -- specifically, the points that lie along the dotted black line in your figure --
to end up with coordinates on the axis.
In other words, the change of coordinates that you need in order to rotate the $x$ axis up to the dotted line is the same as the change of coordinates that you need in order to rotate the dotted line down to the original $x$ axis.

So it turns out that the matrix to rotate the $x$ axis $30$ degrees counterclockwise
(for a change of coordinates) is the same as the matrix to rotate a set of points $30$ clockwise (staying in the original coordinate system): the angle value to put in the formula is negative.

Keep in mind that matrices know nothing about coordinate systems or the positions of points on a graph. Multiplication of a column vector by a matrix merely takes one list of numbers and replaces them with a different list. You need to make sure that the interpretation of those lists are the ones you want.

Comment: I'm almost certain this question has been asked and answered in almost exactly this same form, but I have not found it. I'll be happy to delete this answer if someone can link a question that has an equivalent or better answer for manipulations of the Cartesian plane.

Comment: David thank you so much for this in depth answer! It's totally clear for me now!

Answer (score 0):

We can think of rotating $\theta=\arctan(4/7)\approx 29.74$ degrees clockwise, in this way the line $L:7y-4x=0$ becomes the $x-$axis, so we only need to move point $A(3,1)$

$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\
-sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) \\
\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 65}\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 4 \\
-4 & 7 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $A'=M\cdot A=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 65}\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 4 \\
-4 & 7 \\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
3\\1
\end{bmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{65}\begin{bmatrix}
25\\-5
\end{bmatrix}\approx \begin{bmatrix}
3.1\\-0.62
\end{bmatrix}$
Interpreting what it asks you, it is basically adding the absolute values of the oordinates of the new point, that is |3.1|+|0.6|=3.7

Comment: Thanks you as well Zaragose, it all make sense now :D